# Calling the methods of a subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the classes `Foo` and `Bar`, where Bar inherits from Foo.  Both classes have a `getLength()` method.  I have a function in my main that takes the superclass `Foo` object as a parameter, but it is often passed a `Bar` object.

When the `Bar` object is passed, why does it still call the `Foo` `getLength()` method?

Comment: Is getLength() declared `virtual` in your Foo class?

Comment: Can you post your `main` method code as well as the code that creates the instance of the object that is passed to the main?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if this is a silly question, but did you mark both getLength() functions as "virtual"? (You need to.)

Answer (score 3):

You should define your method as `virtual` if a child class may override it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the method **`virtual`** in the base class.

Remember that classes with any virtual methods should also have a virtual destructor.

Plenty of info here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the method as **virtual**.

```
    class Foo
    {
       virtual double getLength();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is right, of course, in that you need to mark the function as being virtual. But why is this the case?

In C++, non-virtual function calls are resolved at compile time using the **type of the reference**, not the actual type of the object. So this is why in your case the Foo::getLength() function is being called — your function is declared to use a Foo.

If you declare a function to be virtual, however, the actual type of the object determines which function gets called.

Read the [virtual functions section of the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html) for all the gory details.

(Contrast this scenario to a language like Java where instance methods are virtual by default.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare Foo's getLength() function as virtual. Please go through the below link for explanation about virtual functions, hiding virtualization, virtual tables etc
[http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/122-virtual-functions/]

Answer (score 0):

And of course there's the interview question gotcha of one being declared const and the other not!

Answer (score 0):

"virtual" keyword is required in declaration of getLength(). And rememder to create virtual destructor in every class to correctly free the resources. Because if you use a pointer to base class that points to derived and call a non-virtual destructor, only base class destructor will be called. If you add virtual destructor, then derived class destructor will be called first, and base class destructor after it. It is usefull when you obtain extra resources in derived class and need to free it first. And base class destructor can't make it because it didn't know about extra resources.